# Rails devise with omniauth-google-oauth2 image size does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I am building Rails app using devise with `omniauth-google-oauth2`.
Everthing work well but after i authenticate successfully with google,
image hash that i get is: `https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-zE4TdSazXvI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACA/jWRW9BtDAlU/s128-c/photo.jpg?sz=50`
So, this make my image look so small, it is only 50px. 
Although in Devise config i use:

```
    config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "feaeas", "fefaascea", 
  {:image_aspect_ratio => "square",:image_size => 128}
```

How i can i get the large size from google authentication in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue and unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to have Google Plus return a bigger image.  I'm pretty sure it doesn't honor those size attributes anymore.

To fix the issue, I simply substituted the `sz` attribute of the returned string and all is now well.  Here's the Ruby I used:

```
url = auth.info.image.sub('?sz=50', '?sz=256')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depend on this an answer at [How to config image size returned using omniauth-google-oauth2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375666/how-to-config-image-size-returned-using-omniauth-google-oauth2)

This is an issue of `omniauth-google-oauth2` that was reported [here](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/192). So just upgrade your gem to the latest version, this issue will be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Settings below works for me:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, google_client_id, google_client_secret, {
      :prompt => "select_account",
      :scope => "email, profile, plus.me, plus.login",
      :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
      :image_size => 150
    }
```

gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.4.1"