# How to config image size returned using omniauth-google-oauth2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-google-oauth2

I try to config the `omniauth-google-oauth2` with `devise` in my Rails app:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, GOOGLE_APP_ID, GOOGLE_APP_SECRET, {
    scope: 'email, profile, plus.login',
    provider_ignores_state: true,
    prompt: 'select_account',
    image_aspect_ratio: 'square',
    image_size: 50,
    skip_jwt: true
}
```

This work but I try to config the image_size to be larger:

```
image_size: 100,
```

or

```
image_size: {width: 100, height: 100},
```

Based on this [documentation](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#configuration), and it doesn't work, it always returns the image url like `https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-zE4TdSazXvI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACA/jWRW9BtDAlU/s128-c/photo.jpg?sz=50`

This issue was raised at [Rails devise with omniauth-google-oauth2 image size does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496910/rails-devise-with-omniauth-google-oauth2-image-size-does-not-work) as well, but no result on that!

Don't tell me to write this kind of hard code:

```
url = "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-zE4TdSazXvI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACA/jWRW9BtDAlU/s128-c/photo.jpg?sz=50"
url = url.sub('?sz=50', '?sz=100')
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [issue on Github](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/192) about this. The fix is implemented in the new gems. For me it helped to simply update the `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem to a version `>0.2.6`.

Try `bundle update omniauth-google-oauth2` or define a specific version in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.4.1"
```